# How should I have python and node comunicate?

Tags: python, node.js, api, express

So I have certain scripts I want python to run. I basically want the node server to handle the api requests, then hand off the request data to python scripts and then send back the request based on the return value of the python script asynchronously.

What would be the most optimal and scalable way to do this?

Comment: Running python scripts per request won't be very scalable, as you need a new process spawned per request. You may want to build a Python service (essentially, a program that stays running in the background) which will process tasks off a shared queue. You can use a message passing service (ZMQ, Rabbit MQ, etc.) for something like this.

Comment: @RushyPanchal what if the process isn't every request? But like the request is to start an automated task which runs for a couple days so it only gets ran maybe once or twice a day at most usually.

Comment: @RushyPanchal How come spawning a new process on a request isn't scalable?

Comment: Spawning a process has its own overhead. It *can* be scaleable, and you shouldn't take my word without a grain of salt (if it works for your use case and there doesn't seem to be any significant slowdown from spawning one per request, then no harm in doing so) – however, it can also lead to complications that are best avoided (hitting maximum process limit for your system, running out of memory because each process requires a certain amount of memory, etc.).

If it's not happening very often (i.e. you're not spawning every request), then I don't see the harm in it.

Comment: @RushyPanchal Okay awesome. But now here is where it gets tricky. How can I have a request start a script that's ongoing.. then say I want to make a request that stops that script 3 hours later.. Is there a way to do with spawning a request? Or would rabbitmq be a more suitable approach to solve this problem?